# Do I need to update my GPU drivers?

Tags: drivers, wine, performance, gpu

I have the following system running Ubuntu 12.04 with Wine 5.8:
AMD Phenom I x4 2.8 Ghz
XFX GTs 250 1GB
3GB DDR 2 Ram

I have tried the 2 drivers in the additional drivers program and both have the same result (Im currently using the post release). Im getting about 20-30 FPS in all Source games under wine. Garrys Mod, Counter Strike Source and both Left 4 Dead and Left 4 Dead 2.

Anyone know whats going on? I have ran all those games just fine on even weaker systems. I have tried turning off dual core rendering and V Sync isnt enabled.

Thanks!

PS:
I have downloaded all the updates for Ubuntu and still nothing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED:
Install Wine 5.9 to fix this issue.